# Fit images to parent and add nameplates over them

Tags: html, css

I am trying to insert some images and add nameplates over them. Images can be vertical, horizontal, and square. They are static and added manually.

What I expect:

- long images are scaled to fit max-750px wide parent
- tall images are scaled to be no more than 80vh, otherwise fit parent width
- nameplates always cover 100% of image width

Exactly how it should look. Blue is article, parent, 1000px wide. Red frames are containers `.art`, orange is `img`, black is `span` with plain text.

[image: expected result]

What I made so far.

Html:

```
<div class="art">
    <img src="./some/path">
    <span>Image name</span>
</div>
```

Css (scss):

```
.art {
        max-width: 75%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;

        img {
            object-fit: contain;
            width: 100%;
            max-height: 80vh;
        }

        span {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            bottom: 1rem;
            padding: 1rem;
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
        }
    }
```

Problem: works for long images, does not for tall. Nameplates stick outside of image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, check this code. Here is your solution.

add a DIV for Image parent and also add CSS for this.

```css
.art {
  max-width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align:center;
}
.art-container{
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}

  img {
    object-fit: cover;
    height: 80vh;
    max-width:100%;
  }

  span {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    color:white;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 1rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="art">
  <div class="art-container">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/af/8d/63/af8d63a477078732b79ff9d9fc60873f.jpg">
  <span>Image name</span>
    </div>
</div>
 
<!--  https://cdn57.androidauthority.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/00-best-backgrounds-and-wallpaper-apps-for-android.jpg  -->
```